# Should I heat water first and let it cool before watering in winter?

Tags: houseplants, watering

Winter is approaching. It gets cold here. Cold water. Would the cold water shock the roots of the plants or not?

Comment: 4K I am assuming you are talking about your indoor plants.  Why would cold water all of a sudden be a problem?  It was cold in the summer and I'll bet 'dollars to donuts' (whatever that means) you thought they could 'cool' off.  But winter, that same water might be too much?  Sweetie, you are anthropomorphizing, attributing HUMAN feelings to plants.  Plants in soil are far tougher than us hairless humans, grins.  What a plant guy!

Comment: @stormy I agree to that. But in summer, water here is warm. In Winter, water is ice-cold. It is cold right now, and winter has just started. So I thought it better to ask the question here first. :)

Comment: Some gardeners also advocate the slow release of liquid water from ice cubes.  Kind of a good idea if you don't want lots of water draining down the sides of the soil and pot and not being able to be absorbed.  Never have seen any negative reactions with cold water.  Hot water, boiling water now that would be different.  Otherwise, ice water is just fine.  For us humans, drinking pure, unadulterated ice water is the BEST way to re hydrate.  No electrolytes, no sugar, no carbohydrates to slow down getting the water into our bodies.  I haven't yet heard the WHY but this is the truth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very cold water can shock some plants, especially if the surrounding temperature is warm.
You didn't mention where you are, but in most large cities, water has at least some chlorine in it, which is a growth inhibitor.

It's a good idea to let water sit in the pot for a couple hours or more to let it get to room temperature and to allow chlorine to evaporate before watering your plants.

Comment: In 'some' cities?  Find me one city that has tap water services without chlorine or fluorine and a multitude of chemicals.  I have a well so I am lucky.  In the past living in ANY city I would never water with tap water, ever.  Causes any plant to start a slow decline to death.  Allowing chlorine to vaporize is good but there are many more chemicals, salts in tap water. Far better to buy distilled water.  We humans should NOT be drinking tap water yet we believe that our government bends over backwards for our health and well being.  Grins.  My opinion.

Comment: @stormy: you should just forget cities near oceans or in plain. Mountains and hills help. Welcome in countryside cities in Europe.

Comment: This is an important topic for me and certainly others...duh.  Please explain in more detail.  Are you saying Tap water is ok on the coasts?  Plains?  One thing I have found in my bits of research is that our poop gets trucked to the closest PLAIN from the coast and pumped INTO the water table.  Hello.